# SQL database: use one table with 3,5M entries or many tables with less entries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a football game that allows people to create leagues online.

Say I have 1000 league after some time. I store my data in SQL. Should I:

1) Create 1 single database with the table "rosters" and insert all the players of all the leagues into it (which would approximate 3,5 to 4 million entries for 1000 leagues)

2) Create 1 single database with 20 tables "rosters1, rosters2, etc" and split the leagues rosters between those 20 tables

3) Create 1 database for each league with a table "rosters" in each

4) Create 20 databases with one table "rosters" in each and split the leagues rosters between the 20 databases.

What is the best option for performance and quick SQL queries?

Comment: maybe some table data would help, as well as a query or two.  Hard to say with performance without more concrete examples.

Comment: 3.5M is nothing. Keep the relations simple (redundancy is your friend) and the tables slim (redundancy is not your friend). The important thing is you create the right indexes. And ofcourse smart queries that use those indexes. Identical databases or identical tables with silly names are silly. 3.5M is nothing.

Comment: Example of columns:
PlayerID, PlayerName, PlayerTeam, PlayerAwareness, PlayerHitting, PlayerCatching...PlayerContract, PlayerYearsLeft (for a total of 82 columns)

@RUDIE: What do you mean by "creating the right indexes"? What is the role of the indexes in a table (and how to decide which columns to index)? Also, the user "myself" below says in his comment that 3.5 M will take a lot of time to search. Knowing the columns of my "rosters" table (82 columns), do you still recommend using a single table? Thanks in advance

Comment: FWIW, I'd place the threshold from tiny to small in a database at a gigabyte, and the threshold from small to large at a petabyte. In other words, your first use-case is a tiny database. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to learn a few database basics, first, so please spend some time making sure you understand [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and [indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29).

However, in principal, you probably need a "players" table (player id, name, etc), a "roster" table (roster id, name, maybe owner_id), and a player_roster_map (player_id, roster_id) that links the two. You'll probably want a unique constraint on the composite value of player_id and roster_id, and you should have a foreign key constraint on both player_id and roster_id  in that mapping table.

(I'm presuming that players are not really unique per roster; you can still model similarly if there are attributes that are overridden by the person that owns them, but I'm guessing based on my understanding of your description of the model.)

Your database engine will probably index anything that you mark as a primary key by default, and may index anything that you mark as a foreign key, but this is database dependent, and I am not particularly an expert on MySql; you'll need to do some research.

Proper indexes will help you when you execute queries, at a generally small cost in terms of insert performance. If you end up with large numbers of identical values or a high utilization of queries in which only a small range of values (such as time ranges), you may eventually need to understand partitioning, as well. Partitioning allows you to get the benefits of dealing with fairly large number of records without the modeling problems that denormalization would introduce. However, don't prematurely take this step; you'll probably find that a correct database design will be enough with the size of dataset that you're implying.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. However, players evolve differently from league to league, so I'll have to insert a row for each player in each league - the scheme you proposed me would fit for leagues where the player's attributes don't change in each league, but that is not the case here. However, I still could have one table for the players info that don't change such as the name+birthdate+nationality, but would it really have an impact on performance? I'm not so sure (there are only about 8 rows (players personal info) that are common to every league)

Comment: I would recommend modeling the attributes that don't vary as part of the player model as a matter of correctness, first, then worry about performance. Surprisingly, correctness often correlates to performance. But it sounds like you have an additional domain concept to work out; it sounds like have a PlayerLeagueVitals concept, with player_league_id (PK), player_id, league_id, and each of the relevant league-specific player stats.

Comment: Brilliant. So there will be a table for 
(1) players_infos (containing fixed elements such as name and birthdate...)
(2) players_vitals (containing the league-specific player stats and the player's id to join with "players_infos" when required)
I'll put this to try ;)

Comment: Sounds like a good start to me. (I usually just use the noun that most closely maps to the entity, so I'd leave off _infos, but that's just me). The main advantage of modeling distinct entities separately from the start is that, if you discover your modeling was a little bit off, you can more easily move things where you discover they belong than if you started out denormalized.

Comment: I understand, so it is better to build interdependant tables than independant tables that can run solely on their own, because it allows more flexibility. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want option 1 in principle. You have to consider use cases like moving someone from one roster to another: you don't want that to occur across databases. And I imagine many queries that you want to run against all rosters. You may find it helpful to research **partitioning**, even though MySQL does not offer it. (Postgresql does.)

You also need to look at normalization. Example: I assume you have a `teams` table, and PlayerTeam is just a Foreign Key into it (you should index this column in both tables BTW). If this doesn't make sense to you, spend a little time on a database design book or web site.

Comment: I believe some configurations of MySql now support partitioning, but it may depend on your build configuration and possibly the storage engine chosen. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html

Comment: @JasonTrue: quite possible. My familiarity with MySQL is weak; their ISAM tables pretty much.